# iOS: view re-centering on segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a Text Field that moves the view up when it is being edited (as the keyboard would cover the Text Field itself).  However, if the keyboard is still up and it segues to another view controller, then segues back, the Text Field will start editing again.  This is fine, and the view is moved up, but then immediately moved back down (to its original center) and the keyboard stays up.
Thank you for your help

Reference images
(Before leaving screen)
http://prntscr.com/8158nk
(After coming back to screen)
http://prntscr.com/8158uh

Edit: code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
CGPoint origionalCenter;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textBox;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    origionalCenter = self.view.center;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (IBAction)txtBoxBeginEditing:(id)sender {
        //This shifts the view up, as the keyboard will block a good bit of the screen
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(origionalCenter.x, (origionalCenter.y - 264));
    }];

}
- (IBAction)txtBoxEndEditing:(id)sender {

        //This shifts the view back after the keyboard disappears
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(origionalCenter.x, origionalCenter.y);
    }];
}



@end
```

Comment: What are you using to move the view up / down when keyboard shows?

Comment: We need to see your code, we can't guess what the error might be

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Fk4arU1W

Comment: it might be a good idea to keep the text but dismiss the keyboard when there is switching of view controllers